# How to use 2 columns in another table to filter simultaneously in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do something of this sort. I have 2 tables that would look like this:

**Table 1**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | A |
| Three | 3 | C |

**Table 2**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | A |
| Two | 2 | B |
| Three | 3 | C |

Then I would run this code to filter the 2 table.

```
final_table <- table_2 %>%
   filter(col1 %in% table_1$col1 &
          col2 %in% table_1$col2)
```

My understanding was it looked at 'table_1$col1' and 'table_1$col2' where they matched and filtered table_2 whenever the rows have those 2 columns matching.

The result would be:

**Table 2**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | A |
| Three | 3 | C |

I guess the question is, is this a correct way of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do an inner_join

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(table_1, table_2)
```

Comment: thanks that worked!